# Do someone know any good trick to do syntax or brace matching in sublime text on Windows?

Tags: html, css, sublime-text-2

I am using Sublime on Windows. I am using Reindent for make my code format but it's not look well.

I have seen some people use something CLI command based way to format the code. Do someone have any good way to format the code.

the problem is suppose I have a 8 li then one li is 3 tab from left and his close li from first tab.

it's totally make confusion. Do someone have any idea.

Comment: I would have recommended [Artistic Style](http://astyle.sourceforge.net) with a corresponding plugin for Sublime Text such as [this](https://github.com/timonwong/SublimeAStyleFormatter) or [this](https://github.com/robothor/AstyleFormatPlugin), but AS only handles C, C++, C# and Java, not HTML and CSS.

Comment: @Karan Thanks for your help, I am looking for html,css,